# Trying to implement a function with list comprehension, map or a for loop

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm new to python, and I've been trying to implement a function to convert from Gray code to binary, as shown in this figure. [pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzske.png). I've tried doing it with list comprehension:

```
g = [''.join(choice('01') for _ in range(li)) for _ in range(nvar)]

b = [[g[j][i] if i == 0 else b[j][i-1] ^ int(g[j][i], 2) for i in range(li)] for j in range(nvar)]
```

With map:

```
b = list((map((lambda b: b[0][0] = g[0][0] if i == 0 else b[0][i] = int(b[0][i - 1], 2) ^ int(g[0][i], 2) for i in range(li)), g)))
```

And also with a for loop:

```
def grayToBinary(g, nvar, li):
b = []
for i in range(0, nvar):
    #b[i][0] = g[i][0]
    b[i][0].append(g[i][0])
    for j in range(1, li):
        b[i][j].append(int(b[i][j-1], 2) ^ int(g[i][j], 2))
return b
```

I know these are all wrong, but I can't find the right answer. Can this be done with list comprehension or map?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be a little more precise as to what these do that is wrong?

Comment: Could you add an example input and output for this?

Comment: Any kind of appending you can do with a for loop and list, you can do with list comprehension. Map is only useful here if you wanted to apply a function to the items in the list as well. The problem you are having is that b[i] does not exist and you are trying to append to it. Work on getting the for loop to work before you try to jump to list comprehension.

Comment: If I read the pseudocode right, `b[i]` is `g[0]^g[1]^...g[i]` right? So you could at least use `reduce` in a list comprehension, but that will be O(n²) as opposed to O(n) with the loop using the previous element as accumulator.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. 

An in input would be something like this:

`g = [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]`

Or maybe a bitstring, whatever works the best.

Is it possible to do this with list comprehension, considering that b[i] does not exist when I try to append to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted to achieve:

```
def grayToBinary(g, li):
    b = [0]*li
    b[0] = g[0]

    for i in range(1,li):
        b[i] = b[i-1] ^ g[i]

    return b

gray = [0,1,1]
binary = grayToBinary(gray, len(gray))
print("Gray Code =",gray,"Binary =",binary)
```

Output looks like this:

```
Gray Code = [0, 1, 1] Binary = [0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you! So I did it like this: `def grayToBinary(g, nvar, li): b = [[0]*li]*nvar for j in range(nvar): b[j][0] = g[j][0] for i in range(1, li): b[j][i] = b[j][i-1] ^ g[j][i] return b`. But it still doesn't work properly. When I try to change the element i in b[j][i] it changes all the i elements on the j lists. Is this clear?

Comment: Yeah that becomes a problem with python. So, there is a workaround. Instead of using `b[j][0] = g[j][0]` use this `b[j] = g[j].copy()` since if you use to assign a list in python, changing one will automatically change the copies list too. Like "pass by reference" hence we have to use the `.copy()` method for such pruposes

Answer (score 1):

Using keidakida's example:

```
>>> [*itertools.accumulate([0, 1, 1], operator.xor)]
[0, 1, 0]
```